# How to execute a Byte Array in C++

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a encrypted program, I open it with a decrypter, which loads the bytes into a array and decrypts it.

What I want to know is how it would be possible to execute those bytes without having to create another executable.

I read that it is possible using 'Forking', and that is the best way to do so. However I cannot successfully run my code, and it does not return any errors. Here's a sample of what I got :

```
    //<main>
    char* lpMemory;
    lpMemory = (char*)malloc (fileSize);
    memset(lpMemory,0,fileSize);
    memcpy (lpMemory, fileBuf, fileSize);
    RunFromMemory(lpMemory, /* What here? */);

    //</main>

void RunFromMemory(char* pImage,char* pPath)
{
DWORD dwWritten = 0;
DWORD dwHeader = 0;
DWORD dwImageSize = 0;
DWORD dwSectionCount = 0;
DWORD dwSectionSize = 0;
DWORD firstSection = 0;
DWORD previousProtection = 0;
DWORD jmpSize = 0;

IMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Sections[1000];

PROCESS_INFORMATION peProcessInformation;
STARTUPINFO peStartUpInformation;
CONTEXT pContext;

char* pMemory;
char* pFile;
memcpy(&IDH,pImage,sizeof(IDH));
memcpy(&INH,(void*)((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew),sizeof(INH));

dwImageSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage;
pMemory = (char*)malloc(dwImageSize);
memset(pMemory,0,dwImageSize);
pFile = pMemory;

dwHeader = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
firstSection = (DWORD)(((DWORD)pImage+IDH.e_lfanew) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
memcpy(Sections,(char*)(firstSection),sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)*INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections);

memcpy(pFile,pImage,dwHeader);

if((INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
{
    jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
}
else
{
    jmpSize = INH.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    jmpSize += 1;
    jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
}

pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);

for(dwSectionCount = 0; dwSectionCount < INH.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; dwSectionCount++)
{
    jmpSize = 0;
    dwSectionSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].SizeOfRawData;
    memcpy(pFile,(char*)(pImage + Sections[dwSectionCount].PointerToRawData),dwSectionSize);

    if((Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize % INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment)==0)
    {
        jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize;
    }
    else
    {
        jmpSize = Sections[dwSectionCount].Misc.VirtualSize / INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
        jmpSize += 1;
        jmpSize *= INH.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;
    }
    pFile = (char*)((DWORD)pFile + jmpSize);
}


memset(&peStartUpInformation,0,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
memset(&peProcessInformation,0,sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
memset(&pContext,0,sizeof(CONTEXT));

peStartUpInformation.cb = sizeof(peStartUpInformation);
if(CreateProcess(NULL, pPath, NULL /*&secAttrib*/, NULL,false,CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL,NULL,&peStartUpInformation,&peProcessInformation))
{
    pContext.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    GetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
    VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&previousProtection);
    WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),pMemory,dwImageSize,&dwWritten);
    WriteProcessMemory(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)pContext.Ebx + 8),&INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase,4,&dwWritten);
    pContext.Eax = INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase + INH.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
    SetThreadContext(peProcessInformation.hThread,&pContext);
    VirtualProtectEx(peProcessInformation.hProcess,(void*)((DWORD)INH.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),dwImageSize,previousProtection,0);
    ResumeThread(peProcessInformation.hThread);
}
free(pMemory);
}
```

As you might have guessed, 'fileSize' is the size of the program and 'fileBuf' is the Byte array. I am sure that both of those values are correct.

Any links to resources that may help me is appreciated
Thank you very much.

Comment: Cast the array pointer to a void pointer, and then to a function pointer, then call the function pointer? I'm nearly certain that it is undefined behavior, and I'm nearly sure that it is going to work on most computers :)

Comment: Also, you need to somehow get around the execute disable bit feature.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit.

Comment: You are **not** writing a virus, are you?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Exactly what I was thinking. That or using it to encrypt/decrypt a program to keep people from getting around activation.

Comment: There are legitimate uses for this besides writing a virus.

Comment: It's interesting that dlopen requires that the file be represented on disk, but presumably it prevents an awful lot of memory leaks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053664/dlopen-from-memory

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Casting to a function pointer was UB in C++03, but now it's conditionally supported with implementation defined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the bytes in the array actually represent, you might be able to just type-cast the array pointer into a function pointer and then call the "function" like any other.  For that to work, the array would have to reside in executable memory (see `VirtualProtect()`) and contain just the byte representation of assembly instructions and nothing else.

Comment: The thing is that I copied the entire content of the file, do you know a way to get only the code to be executed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:
the easiest way to do it just to cast the pointer of your byte array to a function pointer and after call it. The second way is to use the inline assembler and perform a jmp to your byte array's address. Probably a heap or stack where your array is allocated will not be executable then you need to use the VirtualProtect and related api (for win32 ).