# Load dynamic library from memory

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, dll, module

Is it possible to load a library from memory instead of from the filesystem on mac/gcc?

With windows I'm using MemoryModule but it's obviously not cross-platform compatible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dlopen from memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053664/dlopen-from-memory)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Not quite. That's asking how to 'hack' `dlopen` (*specifically*) to load from memory. I'm wondering about any other possible way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First things first, to do this I advise you use read the [OS X ABI Dynamic Loader Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html).

To do this, you must use the [NSCreateObjectFileImageFromMemory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSCreateObjectFileImageFromMemory) API.

> Given a pointer to a Mach-O file in memory, this function creates and returns an `NSObjectFileImage` reference. The current implementation works only with bundles, so you must build the Mach-O executable file using the `-bundle` linker option.
>
> The memory block that `address` points to, must be allocated with `vm_allocate` (`/usr/include/mach/vm_map.h`).

Make sure to abide by the requirement that `vm_allocate` is used for the memory block containing the module.

Once you acquire the object file image, you must use [NSLinkModule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html) function to link the module into the program.

> When you call this function, all libraries referenced by the given module are added to the library search list. Unless you pass the `NSLINKMODULE_OPTION_PRIVATE`, `NSLinkModule` adds all global symbols in the module to the global symbol list.

After linking, don't forget to clean up by calling the [NSDestroyObjectFileImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDestroyObjectFileImage) function.

> When this function is called, the dynamic loader calls `vm_deallocate` (`/usr/include/mach/vm_map.h`) on the memory pointed to by the `objectFileImage` parameter.

Note that while these functions are deprecated, there is no substitute (to the best of my knowledge) using the suggested alternative `dlopen` et. al.