# How to dynamically load often re-generated c code quickly?

Tags: c, linux

I want to be able to generate C code dynamically and re-load it quickly into my running C program.

I am on Linux, how could this be done?

Can a library .so file on Linux be re-compiled and reloaded at runtime?

Could it be compiled without producing a .so file, could the compiled output somehow go to memory and then be reloaded ? I want to reload the compiled code quickly.

Comment: Are you sure that time is such a big constraint! (Did you measure it)?

Comment: I'm interested to know why do you ask and what kind of application are you coding!

Comment: I am coding a language with Goto statements and global variables. I believe that functions hide the implementation details of the function (encapsulation) and OO encapsulates data. I am against hiding of anything and think that people didn't try hard enough with Gotos and global variables after the "goto is evil" paper. Anyway, I won't argue this point anymore here ! haha... its a bit crazy. So I choose LLVM as I need gotos and C/C++ doesn't allow gotos anymore (except to labels).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you want to do is reasonable, and I am doing exactly that in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a high level domain specific language to extend GCC; MELT is compiled to C, thru a translator itself written in MELT).

First, when generating C code (or many other source languages), a good advice is to keep some sort of [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (AST) in memory. So build first the entire AST of the generated C code, then emit it as C syntax. Don't think of your code generation framework without an explicit AST (in other words, generation of C code with a bunch of printf is a maintenance nightmare, you want to have some intermediate representation).

Second, the main reason to generate C code is to take advantage of a good optimizing compiler (another reason is the portability and ubiquity of C). If you don't care about performance of the generated code (and TCC compiles very quickly C into a very naive and slow machine code) you could use some other approaches, e.g. using some JIT libraries like [Gnu lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) (very quick generation of slow machine code), [Gnu Libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit.html) or [ASMJIT](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit) (generated machine code is a bit better), [LLVM](http://llvm.org) or [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) (good machine code generated, but generation time comparable to a compiler).

So if you generate C code and want it to run quickly, the compilation time of the C code is not negligible (since you probably would fork a `gcc -O -fPIC -shared`  command to make some shared object `foo.so`  out of your generated `foo.c`). By experience, generating C code takes much less time than compiling it (with `gcc -O`). In MELT, the generation of C code is more than 10x faster than its compilation by GCC (and usually 30x faster). But the optimizations done by a C compiler are worth it.

Once you emitted your C code, forked its compilation into a `.so` shared object, you can `dlopen` it. Don't be shy, my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) example demonstrates that on Linux you can dlopen a big lot of shared objects (many hundreds of thousands). The real bottleneck is the compilation of the generated C code. In practice, you don't really need to `dlclose` on Linux (unless you are coding a server program needing to run for months); an unused shared module can stay practically `dlopen`-ed and you mostly are leaking process address space (which is a cheap resource), since most of that unused `.so` would be swapped-out. `dlopen` is done quickly, what takes time is the compilation of a C source, because you really want the optimization to be done by the C compiler.

You coul use many other different approaches, e.g. have a bytecode interpreter and generate for that bytecode, use Common Lisp (e.g. SBCL on Linux which compiles dynamically to machine code), LuaJit, Java, MetaOcaml etc.

As others suggested, you don't care much about the time to write a C file, and it will stay in filesystem cache in practice (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880788/841108)). And writing it is much faster than compiling it, so staying in memory is not worth the trouble. Use some *tmpfs* if you are concerned by I/O times.

### addenda

You asked

> Can a library `.so` file on Linux be re-compiled and *re-* loaded at runtime?

Of course yes: you should fork a command to build the library from the generated C code (e.g. a `gcc -O -fPIC -shared generated.c -o generated.so`, but you could do it indirectly e.g. by running a `make -j`, especially if the `generated.so` is big enough to make it relevant to split the `generated.c` in several C generated files!) and then you dynamically load your library with [dlopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) (giving a full path like `/some/file/path/to/generated.so`, and probably the `RTLD_NOW` flag, to it) and you have to use `dlsym` to find relevant symbols inside. Don't think of *re*-loading (a second time) the same `generated.so`, better to emit a unique `generated1.c` (then `generated2.c` etc...) C file, then to compile it to a *unique* `generated1.so` (the second time to `generated2.so`, etc...) then to `dlopen` it (and this can be done many hundred thousands of times). You may want to have, in the emitted `generated*.c` files, some [constructor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) functions which would be executed at `dlopen` time of the `generated*.so`

Your base application program should have defined a convention about the set of [dlsym](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym)-ed names (usually functions) and how they are called. It should only directly call functions in your `generated*.so` thru `dlsym`-ed function pointers. In practice you would decide for example that each `generated*.c` defines a function `void dynfoo(int)` and `int dynbar(int,int)` and use `dlsym` with `"dynfoo"` and `"dynbar"` and call these thru function pointers (returned by `dlsym`). You should also define conventions of how and when these `dynfoo` and `dynbar` would be called. You'll better link your base application with `-rdynamic` so that your `generated*.c` files could call your application functions.

You **don't** want your `generated*.so` to **re-define** *existing* names. For instance, you don't want to redefine `malloc` in your `generated*.c` and expect all heap allocation functions to magically use your new variant (that probably won't work, and if even if it did, it would be dangerous).

You probably won't bother to `dlclose` a dynamically loaded shared object, except at application clean-up and exit time (but I don't bother at all to `dlclose`). If you do `dlclose` some dynamically loaded `generated*.so` file, be sure that nothing is used in it: no pointers, not even return addresses in call frames, are existing to it.

P.S. the MELT translator is currently 57KLOC of MELT code translated to nearly 1770KLOC of C code.

Comment: Well thats the attraction, the C compiler generates good machine code, also C is a well know language and is easy to understand. Learning LLVM code is some effort, maybe too much effort for me at this time. Other options do not generate efficient code. (not as efficient).

Comment: This is the best answer, but in the end I choose to go with LLVM because I need some features that plain C++ doesn't provide, that being GOTO statements to arbitrary locations (even though that is evil). Still this is the best answer to the question I think.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet's probably the [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) compiler, which allows you to do exactly this --- compile source code, add it to your program, run it, all without touching files.

For a more robust but non-C-based solution, you should probably check out the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) project, which does much the same thing but from the perspective of producing JITs. You don't get to go via C, instead using a kind of abstract portable machine code, but the generated code is loads faster and it's under more active development.

OTOH if you want to do it all manually by shelling out to gcc, compiling a `.so` and then loading it yourself, `dlopen()` and `dlclose()` will do what you want.

Comment: TCC looks encouraging, although I saw this note on the web site: `Note: I am no longer working on TCC. Check the mailing list to get up to date information.`. On the one hand, I see many recent changes in their git repo. But on the other, the last release was 3 years ago. Not quite sure where this leaves things...

Comment: The mailing list is still active, but Fabrice Bellard is working on other things now. Um... it's worth pointing out that tcc *did* start life as an Obfuscated C contest entrant. It's a majestic hack, and does what it does very well, but it's not pretty. I used it with great success a few years ago to load executable code on a platform that didn't support loading executable code.

Comment: But TCC does have a weakness: while its compilation time is good, the generated machine code is very slow. (TCC compiles very quickly C code into slow machine code). If the C code is generated, you might follow some different route....

Comment: So if you care about the dynamically loaded code to run quickly, TCC is not for you, since the code generated by TCC is slow (sometimes 2 to 3 times slower that the code produced by `gcc -O`)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure C is the right answer here? There are various interpreted languages such as Lua, Bigloo Scheme, or perhaps even Python that embed very well into an existing C application. You can write the dynamic parts using the extension language, which will support reloading code at runtime.

The obvious disadvantage is performance - if you absolutely need the raw speed of compiled C then these may be a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload a library dynamically, you can use `dlopen` function (see mans). It opens a library .so file and returns a void* pointer to it, then you can get a pointer to any function/variable of your library with `dlsym`.

To compile your libraries in-memory, well, the best thing I think you can do is creating memory filesystem as described [here](http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/linux_memory_tmp_filesystem_fs.shtml).

Comment: it is `dlopen` and `dlsym` (not `dl_open` ...)!

Comment: Thank you very much, I always make this mistake :(