# swapping out linked shared library at runtime

Tags: linux, shared

Assume I have a process X and then it has loaded some shared library Y into its address space. I then manage to swap this library Y with a different version Yprime, what would be the effect on the process?

Comment: Are you loading the library at runtime manually, or is the loader loading it as it is linked?  http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlsym.3.html

Comment: My answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12322672/841108 might be partly relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No effect. The loader holds the library open until the process ends (or until the library is unloaded via `dlclose(3)`), which means that it keeps using the same (now deleted) library since its blocks still exist on disk.

Comment: What if one overwrites the library file in-place?

Comment: @lanzz: Then undefined behavior results.

Comment: Does it? Once the library has been loaded into memory I don't see why the originating disk blocks would be re-read. Or are the library files mapped in directly instead?

Comment: @boycy: Since the pages are executable and not writeable, the kernel will discard them rather than swap them out if required. When they are reloaded from disk, Bad Things can happen.