# Executing code in mmap to produce executable code segfaults

Tags: c, linux, assembly, function-pointers, currying

I'm trying to write a function that copies a function (and ends up modify its assembly) and returns it. This works fine for one level of indirection, but at two I get a segfault.

Here is a minimum (not)working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define BODY_SIZE 100

int f(void) { return 42; }
int (*G(void))(void) { return f; }
int (*(*H(void))(void))(void) { return G; }

int (*g(void))(void) {
    void *r = mmap(0, BODY_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memcpy(r, f, BODY_SIZE);
    return r;
}

int (*(*h(void))(void))(void) {
    void *r = mmap(0, BODY_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memcpy(r, g, BODY_SIZE);
    return r;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", f());
    printf("%d\n", G()());
    printf("%d\n", g()());
    printf("%d\n", H()()());
    printf("%d\n", h()()()); // This one fails - why?

    return 0;
}
```

I can memcpy into an mmap'ed area once to create a valid function that can be called (`g()()`). But if I try to apply it again (`h()()()`) it segfaults. I have confirmed that it correctly creates the copied version of `g`, but when I execute that version I get a segfault.

Is there some reason why I can't execute code in one mmap'ed area from another mmap'ed area? From exploratory gdb-ing with `x/i` checks it seems like I can call down successfully, but when I return the function I came from has been erased and replaced with 0s.

How can I get this behaviour to work? Is it even possible?

BIG EDIT:

Many have asked for my rationale as I am obviously doing an XY problem here. That is true and intentional. You see, a little under a month ago [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162231/make-me-some-curry) question was posted on the code golf stack exchange. It also got itself a nice [bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16232/42489) for a C/Assembly solution. I gave some idle thought to the problem and realized that by copying a functions body while stubbing out an address with some unique value I could search its memory for that value and replace it with a valid address, thus allowing me to effectively create lambda functions that take a single pointer as an argument. Using this I could get single currying working, but I need the more general currying. Thus my current partial solution is linked [here](https://tio.run/##7Z19c9NItof/z6foHfZu2SGA3l/GQFU2mHtTdYHZJMwwO5dyCVsG1cZ2VrZnyLJ8dq66ZTuOj5plBgh5eVIzEI5aLZ3u0@f3SO5u9@@87vc/fLhVjPvH80Gu7k9Pp/dGo2x8983DrTXrbHBcvNq0lcX4tbZt3bunjt4UU1X999ubbKZOJ3PVn5fl6dbs9CQf5ENVjGet7cfzcX9WTMbtVruztXWrshfjXD1/uv@33u6jRwfKebu78bMq9GT3RW/34L@fP@k@PertPXv@9Ei5XqyqC2dTdZKXak8dzrLxICsHKrzr3Q3uuqtz954fHOx3D3qH@3/v9p792D3oHh7tP9k96qrQ0TXkb6sKilE@nmXHx6dqkM/yclSdODCOPeo@3n@6f7T/7OmhevZ4Udkj9fj50z1tVEc//9A9VO/evTvv69Btt6pf2h21NA/dyuoJq1dZ/YV1VcXQr6yBKBtU1lBYw8oaiRqiyhqLsnFlTYQ1qaypqCHVXjjSDUfbG9zT/rmeqMbVHrq@LK99dKWTrvbSDWU92k83kuW1p6501dW@uomsR3vrprK89teT/nraX88V9XimPxs6VPvrSX897a8XyHq0v57sVk/760l/Pe2vF8t6tL@e7FxP@@tJfz3tr@/I0NP@@rJ/fe2vL/31TQQ3hLD215f962t/femvr/31ZSD72l9f9q@v/fWlv77215fh7Gt/A9m/gfY3kP4G2t9AxnOg/Q1k/wZmzDYMWu1vIOM50P4Gsn8D7W8g/Q20v4GM50D7G8j@DbS/ofQ31P6GMp5D7W8o@zfU/obS31D7G8p4Dk2WakhT2t9Q@htqf0MZz6H2N5T9G2p/Q@lvqP2NZDxH2t9I9m@k/Y2kv5H2N5LxHGl/I9m/kfY3kv5GJi83JGbtbyT7N9L@RtLfSPsbyXiOtL@x7N9Y@xtLf2PtbyzjOdb@xrJ/Y@1vLP2Ntb@xjOdY@xvL/o2NEjVIkfY3lvEca39j2b@x9jeR/iba30TGc6L9TWT/JtrfRPqbaH8TGc@J9jeR/ZtofxPpb6L9TWQ8J0Z7G8RX@5tIfxPtbyrjOdX@prJ/U@1vKv1Ntb@pjOdU@5vK/k21v6n0N9X@pjKeU@1vKvs31f6m0t/U0EYDbtS80QQchjicBuRwDHM4DdDhGOpwGrDDMdzhNICHY8jDaUAPx7CH0wAfjqEPpwE/HMMfTgOAOIZAnAYEcUwbNEHXgrpkmLs1d7lewzmmDZrQq2YvN2iozbSBGzacY9qgCcBqAnPjhtpMG7hJwzmmDZowzHCY6zkNIGnawGuIA69mz4Y2MDTmen5DbaYNvIY4METmNiCZa5jM9aKG2kwbnGFZ9eTw/v178wTxW5md6EeU4aRU09PqKaN6COqr6fx1Vq6eUczTUuvxzou2arWGt269aA8mvTNje2vr10kxUGV@cpz18958XPyzZSzbg2yW7aj698Vh/SjTVu@2VPWzOKAeqLWDHXNoPp4Wr6vHHNV/k5VVRdUzmTbr22wNHuh6O53B7dvLmvRP5Zt62zn3z@ED98xgzn1bXczpqLfqvpoW/8onQ3On21VD3r79tr0qayoYVpf65e1L9acH5umvXVXnrNVfHR6uX1//jPJR/@S0Ndj5S7lzrv5251y5Mp/Ny/GZ7f1W/WfVKdWj67w/U3vHk@m8zBf1a2ey8vVcN9D0F/nAecd92Vkv2J/Mly1pLNO6NWvL8lFXDRe/dFa9sd3aHmX/yOvebbfO38v2Th0@64VH2UnvZFa2azeNz72ZLrf6fzIc9jbPMq20fl5/Mp7O1Hod7dXdt7b71bNvT/d5fcp/vqulC0VeNp5SFX/fWbwayFUV8/PsWB1no1eDbNE1VeRVT@zqZHIyP85m1b9@K2ZvlL6HOti3F9W3Fg2@DISN3jMjoAo5cQOrFwud9ZGQz6qy@pQ7D8@6oVWPIn2RunB9h/qvjg4YfQerFmo13cCO2rzLypv@G9WqL7WMl/Vgrprmx2J053U@zssz/0dZv5x8v17o5xPnp59OZ9//@a/FqrJFlN7fu3Pw8LvqzxcPXzrVX7sPVyf2s2mu3O@XntRnLqOxdebpqqxnK7t5Ueflekutzvd/z/mbNre5zuBz69y0ec3XCb/GdTZtfvO1o4u69qYtaL6f@Fvez6YtbL7H5LLd46Ytar7v9Crc96YtbvbFda6qM5u2xOKge50c3LSlFqe96@60uGeLnrn@jWwJYbRIsxvQPMvmEUYLZrghbfbRNhNGCzO5EQ35@xtSGC0E6Ma07hdqXWG0AK2b0ORfs8mF0QLobko/XHg/CKPlicNz6JzL0TnCaHmE8lx67BL3mDBaHgo9j268at0oWtzymOvxmHs9@lYYLQ/uHg/u17jDhdHyKsLjVcRNiwJhtLxc8Xi5Qmg0GS2vizxeFxEvtngRRssLMI8XYATR7woiYbS80vN4pUdkfX5kCaPlJaXPS0rC7SuFmzBaXrv6vHYlBi8yBoXR8iLZ50UygfnNA1PEi21GM6/GidbLGa3CaHnZ7/OynxC@QiEsjJaPL3w@viCur3pcC6PlAxmfD2QI9msZ7MJo@YjJ5yMmRsDNGQHCaPnQzOdDM4bFDR8Wwmj5GNDnY0DGCmNFjhVhtHywGfDBJgOIAfSJA0gYLR/VBnxUy6hiVH3OqBJGy4fPAR8@M9QYal98qIlot3ycHvBxOuOP8Xcx408YbTvsMUGAQcmg/IaDUhgtUx4CpjwwUhmpl22kCqNlEkfAJA6GL8P3SgxfYbRMSwmYlsKYZkxf3TEtjJaJNgETbRjoDPRrNtCF0TJ1KGDqEKOf0X8TRr8wWiZDhUyGIiWQEm5sShBGy/SukOld5AnyBHliPU8Io2XCWsiENZIHyYPk8R@Thxirlil4IVPwyChkFDLKH8sowmiZVBgyqZA0Q5ohzXzBNCOMtq/yZpokuYfcQ@752rlHGC0TP0MmfpKQSEgkpG@SkITRMpU1ZCorWYosRZa6PFlKGC2Tc0Mm55K6SF2krkueuoTRMt04ZLox@Yx8Rj67ivlMGC0TqCMmUJPkSHIkuWuT5ITRMiU8Yko4mY/MR@a73plPGC2T3CMmuZMOSYekwxuYDkWmsUzbj5i2T44kR5IjyZF1jhRGy0KEiIUIJE4SJ4mTxPmRxCmMlqUVEUsryKZkU7Ip2fT3ZlNhtCwWiVgsQoolxZJiSbFfJMUKo2X5S8TyF/IueZe8S979enlXGC0LeiIW9JCMScYkY5LxBSdjYbQsUYpYokSGJkOTocnQlyFDC6Nl0VXMoivSNmmbtE3avrRpWxgty8hilpGRy8nl5HJy@dXK5cJoWRgXszCOBE@CJ8GT4K9Bghd50rLUL2apH1mfrE/WJ@tf16wvjJbFizGLF5ECpAApQApulBQIo2U5ZsxyTPQBfUAf0Af0QRgtC0xjFpgiGogGooFoIBqNoiGMliWzMUtmURKUBCVBSVCST1cSYbQsAo5ZBIy8IC/IC/KCvHymvAijZVlzzLJmNAfNQXPQHDTna2iOMFoWaics1EaIECKECCFCiC5MiITRsvQ8Yek56oQ6oU6oE@r0bdVJGC2L6RMW0yNZSBaShWQhWZdQskSWt2wPkLA9ADqGjqFj6Bg6dlV0TBgtGx4kbHiAuCFuiBvihrhdaXETRssWDglbOKB4KB6Kh@KheNdP8YTRsilFwqYUyCAyiAwig8jgDZFBYbRss5GwzQbaiDaijWgj2niTtVEYLRuHJGwcgmAimAgmgolgIpgbgimMlq1QErZCQUVRUVQUFUVFUdFPUVFhtGzukrK5C9KKtCKtSCvSirT@YWkVRst2NSnb1aC36C16i96it@jtl9VbYbRswJOyAQ8ijAgjwogwIowIX4AIC42ybCmUsqUQyowyo8woM8qMMn8rZRZGyyZJKZskIdfINXKNXCPXyPWlkmthtGz7lLLtExqOhqPhaDgajoZffg0XRstGVikbWSHsCDvCjrAj7Aj7FRV2YbRszZWyNRdqj9qj9qg9ao/aXye1F0bLZmMpm42BACAACAACgAAgwLVHAGG0bJ@Wsn0aXAAXwAVwAVwAF9xMLhBGy4ZwrsOOcNACtAAtQAvQArQALaxoQRgTG0KwyR0IAUKAECAECAFCgBAfRwhhTG1cwb59cAVcAVfAFXAFXAFX/AGukArr2GiDvQihDWgD2oA2oA1oA9r4YrQhra6NQdhgEQaBQWAQGAQGgUFgkK/MINLq2ciEbSMhE8gEMoFMIBPIBDL5JmQirb6NV9gNE16BV@AVeAVegVfglUvEK9Ia2CiGXT6hGCgGioFioBgoBoq59BQjraGNbdi@FLaBbWAb2Aa2gW1gmyvKNtIa2YiHjVkhHogH4oF4IB6IB@K5VsQjrbYtZ122nIWD4CA4CA6Cg@AgOOgGcJC02nbTddlNFzqCjqAj6Ag6go6goxtLR9Jq2ynYZadgmAlmgplgJpgJZoKZYKZzzCRBwbYLsssuyJAUJAVJQVKQFCQFSUFSn0BS0mrb4dllh2f4Cr6Cr@Ar@Aq@gq/gqz/MV9Jq273aZfdqqAvqgrqgLqgL6oK6oK4vTF3SatuZ22VnblgMFoPFYDFYDBaDxWCxC2ExabXtOu6y6ziEBqFBaBAahAahQWgQ2jckNGm17ajusqM63Aa3wW1wG9wGt8FtcNul4zZpte0W77JbPDQHzUFz0Bw0B81Bc9DcFaE5abXthO@xEz6MB@PBeDAejAfjwXgw3pVmPGm17fLvscs/5Af5QX6QH@QH@UF@kN81JD9ptX2Dgcc3GMCD8CA8CA/Cg/AgPAgP3hgelLxj@3YGj29ngBKhRCgRSoQSoUQoEUq84ZQorbZvnvD45gnYEXaEHWFH2BF2hB1hR9ixgR2l1fatGh7fqgFRQpQQJUQJUUKUECVECVF@MlFKq@0bQzy@MQTOhDPhTDgTzoQz4Uw4E878TM6UVtu3oXh8Gwr0CX1Cn9An9Al9Qp/QJ/T5VehTWuU3vQzyYTY/nq2Q9I5bH3u/9X5r69dJMVDbo@wfea8/L8siL1vTWTnvz9Te8WQ6L3O1XebD9tY7c0oxnqmiPvvePbVX5tksV5ka57@pJeLuKF2ZMqcWVempyt/m/fkse3Wc/8mcWV@yOmd5RfWgurXhnYejUXbSO5mVLWdH7T0/ONjvHvQO9//e7T37sXvQPTzaf7J71N1RPxw8O@oddHcf/dv89tPB/lG3/rX7oru3o57s/tA7/J/dg@6jf@tfd58@e/rzk2fPD3cqz3eUU7WMuY36kvmof3JqLrp2Qztq9Yv1Ps6qOTnO@nlvPi7@eb4O3W6rQqbl1w53zhp/MDHG057uTNH62rhjGl73qhL9sFleX0Of01lr6@ryixsphursGaQ/mVf1PHiwjKLptHg9zgfqjnLbq@hZ3HpL17Tdrkv2s@NjcxHTcPUd1jFnTlveQtWvo6rkpN@aFv/KJ8MN39rL8lUo/e8kG5gwMufV5aoi56o7e4xSDzaeqzobBc@cU@cNmwVXgX@qi653hCi5CE7tVPWrOLwKJF3A/GOzyLlWq0qt/m29qSpOljWumRatNpyUqlVUx5yOKtT9jU7sqNu3i7NePNc0i1xRvFxvnpWxoS0Xx85fQZ9dHRPFl1Ekwuq2cs@Gw@rwprOtZVWLDLaIPxPCYsi0Hi8jYliPkfF81KtuarocKB8fHRcRqMOPxObybj/Shs41ithFV54Tm7Xernr33hf@2bpVjPvH80Gu7k9ng2Jy983DLR0mw8mkZVJqHTWv6r/6y6hZ3GhWhewrta365t50iVFWjFuLXNyvVOJNVqrt6vdff3m5npp1QGWzSdEyh9yXi1A2lzp3yFs/1D93yF8eGvqq9HXjm4Cv7nzHXxw5KavThq3v/uvk/8bfVXqztA89VXpaVP1WZinqLYu6qnR1Ua/1ylLUXbtFI9Vuq79ZdFAXPT9kHd1sHz588D94H9z/Bw). This is the full code that exhibits the segfault I am trying to avoid. While this is pretty much the definition of a bad idea, I find it entertaining and would like to know if my approach is viable or not. The only thing I'm missing is ability to run a function created from a function, but I can't get that to work.

Comment: Are you sure that g's body size is less than 100 bytes?

Comment: Yep, disassemblying it shows it as exactly 76 bytes. I overestimated just to be safe.

Comment: Because using a greater value for BODY_SIZE doesn't produce a segfault (but not a correct value).

Comment: I tried dumping the memory addresses, they are identical (perhaps because of my compiler) both having 76 bytes of assembly followed by 24 bytes of 0.

Comment: On my mac the last call gives a call to h then two calls to g and not g then f...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812869/how-to-write-self-modifying-code-in-x86-assembly/4841784

Comment: **Why do you ask?** One or two paragraphs of motivation might be very useful, so please **edit your question** to motivate it (smells like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) otherwise)

Comment: Good nose. I updated the question. This is a deliberate XY problem. But I want to get Y to work anyways because it's fun and interesting (plus there's a bounty for it).

Answer (score 5):

The code is using relative calls to invoke `mmap` and `memcpy` so the copied code ends up calling an invalid location.

You can invoke them through a pointer, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define BODY_SIZE 100

void* (*mmap_ptr)(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
                  int fd, off_t offset) = mmap;
void* (*memcpy_ptr)(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) = memcpy;

int f(void) { return 42; }
int (*G(void))(void) { return f; }
int (*(*H(void))(void))(void) { return G; }

int (*g(void))(void) {
    void *r = mmap_ptr(0, BODY_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memcpy_ptr(r, f, BODY_SIZE);
    return r;
}

int (*(*h(void))(void))(void) {
    void *r = mmap_ptr(0, BODY_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memcpy_ptr(r, g, BODY_SIZE);
    return r;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", f());
    printf("%d\n", G()());
    printf("%d\n", g()());
    printf("%d\n", H()()());
    printf("%d\n", h()()()); // This one fails - why?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That fails exactly the same way.

Comment: Works fine here. Are you using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit may be using rip-relative addressing for data so the same problem persists as with relative calls.

Comment: interesting, wasn't aware of this... Need to dig on 64 bit adressing seriously.

Comment: Not accepting because I already tried it, but very good thing to notice either way (the very first thing I realized was that any functions I pass to these copied functions had to be stored in a pointer as they would be relatively jumped to).

Comment: In 64 bit it also works if you can get your compiler to not emit rip relative addressing, for example by using `-mcmodel=large`. Note that I had to increase `BODY_SIZE` to accomodate larger code.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to write a function that copies a function

I think that is pragmatically not the right approach, unless you know very well machine code for your platform (and then you would not ask the question). Be aware of [position independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) (useful because in general [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) would use [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and give some "randomness" in the addresses). BTW, genuine [self-modifying machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) (i.e. changing some bytes of some existing valid machine code) is today [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) and [branch-predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) unfriendly and should be avoided in practice.

I suggest two related approaches (choose one of them).

- Generate some *temporary* C file (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12322672/841108)), e.g. in `/tmp/generated.c`, then fork a compilation using `gcc -Wall -g -O -fPIC /tmp/generated.c -shared -o /tmp/generated.so` of it into a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)), then [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (for [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading)) that `/tmp/generated.so` [shared object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) plugin (and probably use [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to find function pointers in it...). For more about shared objects, read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper. Today, you can `dlopen` many hundreds of thousands of such shared libraries (see my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) example) and C compilers (like recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) are fast enough to compile a few thousand lines of code in a time compatible with interaction (e.g. less than a tenth of second). Generating C code is a [widely used](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065) practice. In practice you would represent some [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) in memory of the generated C code before emitting it.
- Use some [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library, such as [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), etc.... which would generate a function in memory, do the required [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)), and give you some pointer to it.

BTW, instead of coding in C, you might consider using some [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language implementation (such as [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) for Common Lisp, which compiles to machine code at every [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interaction, or any dynamically contructed [S-expr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) program representation).

The notions of [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) and of [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) are worthwhile to know. Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) and perhaps [*Lisp In Small Pieces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces) (and of course the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), for general compiler culture).

Comment: Astute of you to notice that I'm effectively trying to make a closure. As per my edit, I actually name the structure that I end up populating in the generated code a closure so yeah - I'm trying to perform JIT recursively.

Comment: Then consider using some JIT compiling library

Answer (score 0):

> this question was posted on code golf.SE

I updated [the 8086 16-bit code-golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/117017/arbitrary-length-currying/117188#117188) on the sum-of-args currying question to include commented disassembly.

You might be able to use the same idea in 32-bit code with a stack-args calling convention to make a modified copy of a machine code function that tacks on a `push imm32`.  It wouldn't be fixed-size anymore, though, so you'd need to update the function size in the copied machine code.

In normal calling conventions, the first arg is pushed last, so you can't just *append* another `push imm32` before a fixed-size `call target` / `leave` / `ret` trailer.  If writing a pure asm answer, you could use an alternate calling convention where args are pushed in the other order.  Or you could have a fixed-size intro, then an ever-growing sequence of `push imm32` + call / leave / ret.

The currying function itself could use a register-arg calling convention, even if you want the target function to use i386 System V for example (stack args).

You'd definitely want to simplify by not supporting args wider than 32 bit, so no structs by value, and no `double`.  (Of course you could chain multiple calls to the currying function to build up a larger arg.)

Given the way the new code-golf challenge is written, I guess you'd compare the total number of curried args against the number of args the target "input" function takes.

---

I don't think there's any chance you can make this work in pure C with just `memcpy`; you have to modify the machine code.