# Call dlopen with file descriptor?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dlopen

I want to open a shared object as a data file and perform a verification check on it. The verification is a signature check, and I sign the shared object. If the verification is successful, I would like to load the currently opened shared object as a proper shared object.

First question: is it possible to call `dlopen` and load the shared object as a data file during the signature check so that code *is not* executed? According to the man pages, I don't believe so since I don't see a flag similar to `RTLD_DATA`.

Since I have the shared object open as a data file, I have the descriptor available. Upon successful verification, I would like to pass the descriptor to `dlopen` so the dynamic loader loads the shared object properly. I don't want to close the file then re-open it via `dlopen` because it could introduce a race condition (where the file verified is not the same file opened and executed).

Second question: how does one pass an open file to `dlopen` using a file descriptor so that `dlopen` performs customary initialization of the shared object?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, even if I replied to some points. You really should explain a lot more your motivations. Why do you want to do all this? What kind of software are you thinking of? Show some use case scenarii.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Explain all the things in the comments, in a more structured way, within you edited question. Define in your question what "authentic" or "approved" plugins means?

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, you probably could `dlopen` some `/proc/self/fd/15` file (for file descriptor 15).

`RTLD_DATA` does not seems to exist. So if you want it, you have to patch your own dynamic loader. Perhaps doing that within [MUSL Libc](http://musl-libc.org/) could be less hard. I still don't understand why you need it.

You have to trust the `dlopen`-ed plugin somehow (and it will run its constructor functions at `dlopen` time).

You could analyze the shared object plugin before `dlopen`-ing it by using some [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) parsing library, perhaps [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html) or `libbfd` (from [binutils](http://sourceware.org/binutils/)); but I still don't understand what kind of analysis you want to make (and you really should explain that; in particular what happens if the plugin is indirectly linked to some bad behaving software). In other words you should explain more about your verification step. Notice that a shared object could overwrite itself....

Alternatively, don't use `dlopen` and just `mmap` your file (you'll need to parse some [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and process [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)); see [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](https://www.iecc.com/linker/) for details, and look into the source code of your [`ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), e.g. in [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)).

Perhaps using some [JIT generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques might be useful (you would JIT generate code from some *validated* data), e.g. with [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), or [libjit](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=libjit) or [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) (or even [LuaJit](http://luajit.org/) or [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/)) etc...

And if you have two file descriptors to the same shared object you probably won't have any race conditions.

An option is to build your ad-hoc static C or C++ source code analyzer (perhaps using some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) provided by you). That plugin might (with months, or perhaps years, of development efforts) check some property of the user C++ code. Beware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) (limiting the properties of every static source code analyzer). Then your program might (like my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) does, or like [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) will soon do, in mid 2020, or like the obsolete [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) did a few years ago) take as input the user C++ code, run some static analysis on that C++ code (e.g. using your GCC plugin), compile that C++ code into a *temporary* shared object, and `dlopen` that shared object. So read Drepper's paper [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Comment: Hi Basile. "You have to trust the dlopen-ed plugin somehow." Actually we don't :) Trust is what we use when we don't have effective security controls in place. In this case, I have at least two controls: (1) a signature check; or (2) a self-authenticating URL.

Comment: "RTLD_DATA does not seems to exist." Yes, correct (it's the one I would like to use for simplicity if it existed).

Comment: "... you probably could dlopen some /proc/self/fd/15 file." That's clever. I'll try it when I get a chance.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch :`Alternatively, don't use dlopen and just mmap your file`This would require parsing ᴇʟꜰ header isn’t it ? *(alors que `dlopen()` le fait tout seul)*

Comment: "This would require parsing ᴇʟꜰ header" - you'll still need to `dlopen` it afterwards, after verification (trust me, you don't want to handle runtime relocation processing yourself) which introduces a race condition.

Comment: No, you can call `mmap` directly, exactly like `dlopen` does; of course you will need to handle ELF relocation. But you could find existing open source code doing that.

Comment: Anyone tested "/proc/self/fd/15" solution - does it really works? I'am looking for the Linux version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053664/dlopen-from-memory/42196828#42196828

Comment: @DmitrySychov: Please explain (perhaps in a new question) why you need such a solution and what is the actual use case.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053664/dlopen-from-memory/42196828#42196828) basically explains it all. It's very useful when someone does not want to leave the traces of .so on the disk(security reasons) but load->init .so image purely from the mem instead.. please see the link for FreeBSD solution.

Comment: But then, why do use an `.so` file ? The correct approach is to generate code in memory. Look into [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) or similar libraries. **Don't use files**

Comment: Its just complex - FreeBSD solution is slick and simple. Why should I generate code in memory when I can just map its compiled binary presentation into shared block and load it like a file..

Comment: Generating code is hard, whatever way you do it. Even generating temporary C files and compiling them (I love doing that) is not trivial