# Need an API that allows me to load a shared object from a memory address

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-linking, dlopen

The dlopen prototype:
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);

What I need is:
void *dlopen(const char *pBufferWithSoContents, int flag);

I don't want to store the library.so in a filesystem. I want to store it in a memory buffer, not in a files system. Anyone know of any solutions I could use?

Comment: Do you have a filesystem? Have you tried to write your data to a temporary file and than use dlopen?

Comment: I have a file system but I don't want to use it. This is a specialized use case.

Comment: You might as well static link it which is what you are basically describing? Tell me why you can't just static link which means the code becomes part of the executable.

Comment: depending on your use case, the most pragmatic solution might be to just dump a file into `/tmp`, which may or may not be backed by on-disk storage

Comment: Tmp file is the solution check my answer see if it helps I haven't tested the code.

Comment: see also the related question [dlopen from memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053664/dlopen-from-memory?rq=1)

Comment: Yes this is a possible duplicate. But I might be wrong. Just flagged it for review.

Comment: Could you give us more information about your real problem? Explaining why you cannot create a temporary file or static link your object?

Comment: @Christoph - thanks, that guy wants the same thing which renders my a post a re-post. Unfotunately, there isn't any way to this.

Comment: See also https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767

Answer (score 0):

```
void *dlopen(const char *pBufferWithSoContents, int size, int flag) {

FILE* handle = fopen("lib.tmp", "w");

fwrite(pBufferWithSoContents, sizeof(char), size, handle);

fclose(handle);

void * ptr = dlopen("lib.tmp", flag);

remove("lib.tmp"); // Tmp file delete it.

return ptr;

}
```

I must admit not tested but essentially create a tmp file. You said its in memory but not in hard disk just temporarily save it on the disk load it using the dlopen posix call and just delete the temporary file.

Comment: You are still writing the lib to the file system by storing it lib.tmp, albeit briefly.

Comment: That is the point there is no way you can load it in memory. If you can answer my question why can't you just temporarily store it on the disk? Is there some performance gain, I would not think not.