# System.loadLibrary() from byte array

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'd like to encrypt my native libraries and decrypt them on runtime before doing `System.loadLibrary("foo")`

`System.loadLibrary()` and `System.load()` only takes `libname` and `filename`

I've already looked at Runtime.java source code, and the library loading methods seems to depend on a [native function](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/libcore/ojluni/src/main/java/java/lang/Runtime.java#1077)

Is there a workaroud for this ?

Comment: Why? You'd have to distribute the decryption key in order for any app to use the libraries. There's no point to a security system based on, "These libraries are encrypted, so here's the decryption key so you can use them."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm aware of this.

Comment: I've seen other cases, where a "fat jar" embeds the binary library as a resource, but the answer has always been "cache it on disk".

Comment: This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053664/dlopen-from-memory suggests that the OS-level load-from-memory cannot be done portably, but you could pull some tricks on FreeBSD.

Comment: This would be very helpful, if we could load java libs from byte array. Then this would allow to create a self contained binaries binaries from JNI, firstly from C executable we could call JNI_CreateJavaVM() then some API to load jarlib from byte array. 

The byte array by itself would be blob generated by some C precompiler/blob serializer and stored in C static array.

The benefit of all this would be that we could delver to customer kind of "standard os" executable and not the java classes.

Meanwhile System.load();